# Flag without review on a deleted post

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags

I created a flag a while ago (28-mar) and it still not reviewed. But the flagged post doesn't exist anymore.

[image: Flag]

Could someone check this for me? I can't open a flag to this problem =X So I'm posting it in meta.

Comment: The post was probably deleted.  We can't check it without a link.

Comment: Can at least remove that from my list? it's annoying >.<

Comment: [Deleted by @agent86](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/111856/9983)

Comment: I wiped it out, using my normal method of pressing the "delete" button until it is no more, but I've no idea what the issue is here.  I've raised this to a SE employee, who might say "this is working as designed" or maybe respond here if there's something else to be done.

Comment: Thanks for your help @agent86 the ghost flag in my list is really creeping me out o.O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asked a dev about this. Yay Jarrod!

[badp's answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7103/12936) is almost on the right of it. The source of the problem is indeed due to "convert to comment". The conversion code for handling flags will properly handle any flags for moderator attention that are cast on the post, but it will not handle spam/offensive flags. The flag remains on the answer, but then it expired over time and was auto-invalidated. The flag history page was not aware that this happened, though, so it is not showing the proper "declined" that it should.

This missing indication should be fixed at some point, as well as the behavior of the flag handling.

Comment: Uya, I discovered a bug on SE! Do I receive a cookie ? =D Thanks for the help Grace Note. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @Michel, yes, you do get a cookie!  It's already in your browser.  You can print it out and eat it, but it's not that tasty.

Answer (score 4):

Well, here's an educated guess. Take a peek here at this:

[image]

What happened here is that this post received 4 flags; 3 were correctly dismissed ("deleted") as helpful by agent as he deleted the post, while yours... died 2 days ago. However, the post wasn't just deleted, it was [converted to a comment.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/110179/how-do-i-slash-command-spawn-mobs/111856#comment150032_110232)

<s>My guess is that since comments can *also* be flagged as spam, the spam flag remained on the comment itself, although kind of in limbo (I certainly don't recall seeing a spam flag on that comment, or I would've dismissed it — and *not* as helpful, either).</s> ← *This was wrong, see [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7104/23). Offensive/spam flags are simply ignored on conversion.* Flags eventually expire automatically and the timestamp tooltip, 2013-03-31 03:00:05Z, suggests that this is what happened.

At any rate, please consider your flag dismissed and declined. :)

Comment: I don't mind it being declined. but... could you PLEASE '-' remove it from my list? or put a "declined" on that?

Comment: @Michel no can do